# Lua & C++ API getting the executing information

Tags: c++, debugging, lua

In Lua I have a function called `utils.debug()` and what I would like to do is use it in my Lua code as follows:

```
function Foo:doSomething
    if (/* something */) then
        print("Success!")
    else
        utils.debug()
    end
end

function Foo:doSomethingElse
    if (/* something else */) then
        print("Awesome!")
    else
        utils.debug()
    end
end
```

I would like to use it throughout my Lua code to help me debug. As a result, I would like my C++ code to know where in the Lua code the `utils.debug()` was called from. I looked into `lua_Debug` and `lua_getinfo` and they seem pretty close to what I want, but I'm missing a piece:

```
int MyLua::debug(lua_State* L)
{
    lua_Debug ar;
    lua_getstack(L, 1, &ar);
    lua_getinfo(L, ??????, &ar);

    // print out relevant info from 'ar' 
    // such as in what function it was called, line number, etc
}
```

Is this what the lua_Debug struct is for or is there another facility or method I should use to do this?

Comment: fyi lua has a support mailing list you could also try if you dont get a satistfactory answer here.

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what you're asking. Are you asking how to use `lua_getinfo`? Because the manual has [pretty good documentation on what it does](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_getinfo).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what I use to produce a Lua stack trace:

```
lua_Debug info;
int level = 0;
while (lua_getstack(l, level, &info)) {
    lua_getinfo(l, "nSl", &info);
    fprintf(stderr, "  [%d] %s:%d -- %s [%s]\n",
        level, info.short_src, info.currentline,
        (info.name ? info.name : "<unknown>"), info.what);
    ++level;
}
```

See the [documentation for `lua_getinfo`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_getinfo) for more info.